# Append an array using a subprogram in C

Tags: c, arrays

I've been trying to create a subprogram that adds an given element (x) to the end of an array. This is what I've done so far:

```
typedef int TAB[50];
TAB t;
int N;

int append(int x){
    N++;
    t[N - 1] = x;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int i;
    N = 5;
    TAB t = {1,2,6,8,9};
    append(5);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("%d ", t[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see with the function append I increase the length of the array and then assign the integer 5 as its last element. However when I run the program this is the result I get:

```
1 2 6 8 9 0
```

I expect the 0 to be a 5 but that is not the case. I think the array increased in size but the last element did not take the value I expected... any suggestions?

Comment: `TAB t;int N;` --> `TAB t={1,2,6,8,9}; int N=5;`, `N++; t[N - 1] = x;` --> `t[N++] = x;`

Comment: What's a subprogram?

Comment: @Qix: An anachronism:-} older than C. C does not have "subprograms", but functions.

Comment: @Qix It's another name for a procedure or function :-) I don't know why I used the word subprogram instead, though...

Comment: Do you mean _subroutine_?

Comment: @Qix Yeah, that too :)

Answer (score 2):

You have two variables with the name `t`. The `append` function only knows about the “global” variable (from line 2), and the `for` loop in `main` only knows about the “local” variable (from line 14).

Answer (score 2):

In your source code, you have declare twice `TAB t`. The first is global and visible from the `append()` function, but hidden by the second declaration inside the `main()` function => `TAB t = {1,2,6,8,9};`.

If you replace the global declaration `TAB t;` by the local initialized form `TAB t = {1,2,6,8,9};`, your array will be visible from both `append()` and `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the function name `t`  is the name declared in the declaration in the global namespace before the function declaration

```
TAB t;
^^^^^
int N;

int append(int x){
    N++;
    t[N - 1] = x;
    ^^
    return 0;
}
```

So the function changes the global array. The array declared in main

```
int main(){
    int i;
    N = 5;
    TAB t = {1,2,6,8,9};
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is not visible in the function.

The reason of the mistake is that the function refers to global variables and as such it has so-called side effect.

Try not to use global variables in function definitions.

Also you forgot to increase N after appending a new value.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   50

typedef int TAB[N];

size_t append( int *a, size_t n, int value )
{
    a[n++] = value;

    return n;
}

int main( void )
{
    TAB t = { 1, 2, 6, 8, 9 };
    size_t n = 5;

    n = append( t, n, 5 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", t[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 6 8 9 5
```